How to solve problem: The Linked File was unavailable and couldn´t be updated - Power Point VBA
I am automating a Power Point based on VBA code and everything works perfect except when I run the macro twice and I have the excel document open to which many other shapes in the presentation are linked. The macro updates the shapes in the power point which are linked to one specific excel document. The first time I run the macro with the excel open, it updates everythging well and the second time I run the macro it sends me the error in the photo attatched. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? The excel document never moves from place and is always on the same directory which is the company directory, not my personal computer. I don´t know if this means it is in One Drive or in the server or the company or what exactly this implicates.
Thanks for your help!
I have this code for updating the link of each shape:
Public Sub LinkformatUpdateDashboard(LF As LinkFormat, oShp As Shape, ShapeTag As String, ShapeVal As String, SldIndex As Long, Optional Einzeln As Boolean = False)
Dim PHeightOld As Single, PWidthOld As Single, PLeftOld As Single, PTopOld As Single, LockR As MsoTriState

    'Stablish the parameters of the shape
    With oShp
        PHeightOld = .Height
        PWidthOld = .Width
        PLeftOld = .Left
        PTopOld = .Top
    End With
    
    'Update Link
    If Einzeln Or Not wbUP Is Nothing Then
        LF.Update
    Else
        Set wbUP = GetWB(LF.SourceFullName, oShp, wbUP_IsNew)
        LF.Update
    End If
    
    If Not Einzeln Then
        Call UpdateProgressBar(True)
    Else
        GlobalShapeTagName = ShapeTag
        GlobalShapeTagVal = ShapeVal
    End If

Normalfall:
    'alte Parameter
        Call ShapeFormat(oShp, PHeightOld, PWidthOld, PLeftOld, PTopOld, msoFalse)
    End If
End Sub


There's no "photo attached".  We'd likely also need to see the code which calls your sub LinkformatUpdateDashboard  since that may be where the problem is.

@TimWilliams sorry, I couldn´t attatch photo but the error says: Error in UpdateSlideShapes: LinkFormat(unknown member): Invalid request. The linked file was unavailable and couldn´t be updated. I can´t put the GetWb sub here since the space is limited

There's not really enough here to work with.  You haven't even told us which specific line the code fails on.

Have you stepped through the code and examined the values of LF.SourceFullName to verify that it's a valid string and that it points to an existing file? In fact it's always a good idea to validate the supposed linked file's existence before trying to update the link.  Also if someone linked from Excel to PPT w/o first saving the Excel file, you'll get linked files with no source. They can't be updated. Or if someone links from Excel to a chart datasheet in a PowerPoint chart, PPT will tell you that it's linked but won't let you don anything with it.
